# How to find column name that contains specific string value using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to find column name contains particular string value  in my table sku_config using oracle.
for example my string is TRP , I need to find the column name that is having value 'TRP' in mytable.
here column name can be any column belongs to my table.
Here is psudo code for my requirement.
select column_name from sku_config where contains 'TRP'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xmlquery` as follows:

```
SELECT column_name FROM
(select column_name,
  to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
    passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
      'select count(1) as c '
      || 'from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || column_name || ' LIKE ''%TRP%'''))
  returning content)) as c
from all_tab_columns
where TABLE_NAME = 'SKU_CONFIG')
WHERE C > 0;
```

Example:

Current data of sample table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM ABC;

NAME            DE
--------------- --
TEJASH2         SO
TEJASH3         DO
ABC             SO
XXXXXXXXX       SO
A               A
B               B
TEJASH1         SO

7 rows selected.
```

Searching for `TEJASH` string

```
SQL> SELECT column_name FROM
  2  (select column_name,
  3    to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
  4      passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
  5        'select count(1) as c '
  6        || 'from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || column_name || ' LIKE ''%TEJASH%'''))
  7    returning content)) as c
  8  from all_tab_columns
  9  where TABLE_NAME = 'ABC')
 10  WHERE C > 0;

COLUMN_NAME
-------------
NAME
```

Searching for `SO` string

```
SQL>
SQL>
SQL> SELECT column_name FROM
  2  (select column_name,
  3    to_number(xmlquery('/ROWSET/ROW/C/text()'
  4      passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml(
  5        'select count(1) as c '
  6        || 'from ' || table_name || ' WHERE ' || column_name || ' LIKE ''%SO%'''))
  7    returning content)) as c
  8  from all_tab_columns
  9  where TABLE_NAME = 'ABC')
 10  WHERE C > 0;

COLUMN_NAME
------------
DEPT

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to find a column with a specific string.

```
select COLUMN_NAME
from TABLE_NAME
where COLUMN_NAME="STRING"  
group by COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the *names* of the columns in a table that look like something, then use [`user_tab_columns`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4462.htm#REFRN26277):

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'sku_config' and
      column_name like '%TRP%';
```